# wp_insert_post inserts post but isn't visible on front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a post in WordPress using wp_insert_post, the code I'm using to insert is fairly straightforward;

```
$id=wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_status'       =>  'publish',
    'post_title'        =>  $_POST['name'],
    'post_name'         =>  $_POST['name'],
    'post_type'         =>  'tasks',
    'post_content'      =>  $_POST['name'],
    'post_excerpt'      =>  $_POST['name'],
    'post_author'       => '1'
));
```

It gets called and it runs without issue, the post is shown in the WordPress admin, but doesn't show on the front end until I go into the post in `wp-admin` and click `Update`. I can't see why I'm having to do this; it feels like I'm missing something obvious but just can't seem to figure out what.

The user that runs the code has *Administrator* permissions and the post itself is marked as *Published*.

Comment: Ensure that your post_type named `tasks` isn't excluded by your query in the frontend!

Comment: Try sanitizing the post_name (the slug) like so `'post_name' => sanitize_title_with_dashes( $_POST['name'] )`. Not sure what happens if you try to set a slug with spaces. Other than that the code looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress 4.9.7 you do not need to update `_visibility` post meta. Just use the wp_insert_post()`function and pass the`post object` to it.

```
$id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_status'       =>  'publish', // Default is 'draft'.
    'post_title'        =>  $_POST['name'],
    'post_name'         =>  $_POST['name'],
    'post_type'         =>  'tasks', //  Default is 'post'.
    'post_content'      =>  $_POST['name'],
    'post_excerpt'      =>  $_POST['name'],
    'post_author'       => '1' // Default is the current user ID.
));
```

Comment: As of now, in 4.9.7 WP Version, i tried doing this and didn't work. Do you have any new fixes?
The code i tried: $args = array('post_type'=>$post_type,'post_title'=>$name, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'post_author'=>1);$post_id = wp_insert_post($args); update_post_meta($post_id, '_visibility', 'visible'

Comment: for WordPress 4.9.7 you do not need to update the post meta. Just use `wp_insert_post()` function and passed the `post object`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. There was a pre_get_post hook action that selected a meta value for the order by, so it wasn't being show because of that. Once i changed, all okay...